# How to get data from PHP request in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I want to make a simple rest service request with angular for the following PHP code. For some reasons the request throws an error.

[Live code](https://jsfiddle.net/0d1arfnb/)

**PHP**

```
<?php
  /* Simple array */
  $json = array("status" => 0, "msg" => "Request method accepted");

  /* Output header */
  header('Content-type: application/json');
  echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

**Angular**

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('Main', function($scope,$http,$log){
  $http.get({
    method : "GET",
    url : "http://my-host-example/webservice.php",
    headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'}
  }).then(function(response){
    $log.debug('success',response);
  },function(response){
    $log.debug('error',response);
  });
});
```

Comment: what error does it throw ?

Comment: I think you do not need to set header for response Just " echo json_encode($json); exit(); " will be good.

Comment: @Jigar I placed the live code in jsfiddle, it enters the error function, status 404

Comment: @Kashyap tried and didn't work

Comment: remove  this line `headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'}`, you are not passing any data with ajax request.

Comment: @Jigar ok, removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you tried this way ?

```
$http.get("http://webenergized.com/webservice.php").then(function(response){
        $log.debug('success',response);
      }, function(response){
        $log.debug('error',response);
      });
    });
```

and add in your php

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Comment: Yes I did, for some reasons in jsfiddle throws error 404 not found, but in w3schools editor (with same code) it works....

Comment: it's certainly because the php url should be a https:// like fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/0d1arfnb/)

Answer (score 1):

404 ?

- hosts ok ?
- permissions to read file ok ?
- file have run permission?
- owner is www:www ?

**PHP**

```
<?php

die(json_encode(['test' => 'test']));
```

**Angular**

```
$http.get(url); //return promise for service
```

**Cross domain ?**

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Answer (score 0):

error status 404 refers file not found at the given url please check the path or call ajax function like this works fine for me.

```
                $http({
                    url:'ajaxurl',
                    data:{
                        "key":'value',
                         "key":'value'
                    },
                    method:'get'
                }).
                success(function(data){
                    'your code here'

                }).
                error(function(data){
                })
```

Comment: NP bro i didn't use headers config